# MDriven: Method not found: Eco.Persistence.SyncVersion

Tags: exception, .net-6.0, app-config, mdriven

We have a legacy solution that started at ECO times 10+ years ago. It contains one model project and one ecospace project, and also one WinForms project and one ASP.NET project.

We now need to make a few calls into the ecospace assembly from a new .NET 6 project. For this purpose we've packed the model and ecospace assemblies into two NuGet packages and consume them from the new .NET 6 project.

It builds, but when we try to run it, the EcoSpace constructor throws an exception:

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Eco.Persistence.SyncVersion
Eco.Persistence.ISyncSink.Submit(Eco.Persistence.CommitBlock, System.Object)'.
```

What might be the cause?

The legacy solution has `app.config`/`web.config` related to ECO/MDriven and as far as I understand the framework reads that config itself rather than our code supplying it to the framework. I suspect that the error might be caused by missing config. Plausible? If so, how do we provide that config to the framework in a .NET 6 context?

The legacy solution is currently at ECO version 7.0.0.10021, in case it's relevant. And yes, we are aware that this version is very old.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague discovered that referencing an up to date version of Eco.Persistence assembly instead of getting an outdated version loaded from gac at runtime solved the issue.